# Can't create a version specific values folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-version

[image: What I see when I right click res>New Resource Directory]

This is what I see when I right click `res>New Resource Directory`. I've looked this up, and it's supposed to give me and option for a version. But I don't see it. I want to create a Values v-21 directory. Help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll down and select [image: <code>version</code>] as the qualifier, then specify the version, in this case 21. Note that in the screenshot it shows [image: Dimension] as selected but that's simply because the item you move to the right disappears when it's added to the chosen qualifiers

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I didn't notice that.